# Kafka Consumer not fetching latest data shared by producer

Tags: kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka .Currently i was trying  to use an existing program (Kafka Consumer) to fetch data from Kafka Provider .I am able to retrieve the data in a single fetch .

But my concern is, 
Once the fetch by my Consumer  got over  , Provider can share new set of data again.
how can i ensure my consumer will fetch those data ,that Provider sends once my earlier fetch was completed .

Please find the code below.

```
        import kafka.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
        import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;
        import kafka.javaapi.consumer.ConsumerConnector;

        import java.util.HashMap;
        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;
        import java.util.Properties;
        import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
        import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

        public class ConsumerGroupExample {
            private final ConsumerConnector consumer;
            private final String topic;
            private  ExecutorService executor;

            public ConsumerGroupExample(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId, String a_topic) {
                consumer = kafka.consumer.Consumer.createJavaConsumerConnector(
                        createConsumerConfig(a_zookeeper, a_groupId));
                this.topic = a_topic;
            }

            public void shutdown() {
                if (consumer != null) consumer.shutdown();
                if (executor != null) executor.shutdown();
                try {
                    if (!executor.awaitTermination(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)) {
                        System.out.println("Timed out waiting for consumer threads to shut down, exiting uncleanly");
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Interrupted during shutdown, exiting uncleanly");
                }
           }

            public void run(int a_numThreads) throws InterruptedException {
                Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
                topicCountMap.put(topic, new Integer(a_numThreads));
                Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumer.createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);

                //List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);

              //  System.out.println(streams.size());
                // now launch all the threads
                //
                executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(a_numThreads);
                List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = null;
                // now create an object to consume the messages
                //
                int threadNumber = 0;
    boolean keepRunningThread = false;
    for (;;) {  

                    streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
                    for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
                        keepRunningThread =true;
                        executor.submit(new ConsumerTest(stream, threadNumber,keepRunningThread ));
                        //threadNumber++;

                    }
                    //TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
                    //System.out.println("Going to sleep ");
                }

            private static ConsumerConfig createConsumerConfig(String a_zookeeper, String a_groupId) {
                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("zookeeper.connect", a_zookeeper);
                props.put("group.id", a_groupId);
                props.put("zookeeper.session.timeout.ms", "1600");
                props.put("zookeeper.sync.time.ms", "200");
                props.put("consumer.timeout.ms","10");
                props.put("auto.offset.reset", "smallest");
                props.put("auto.commit.interval.ms", "1000");
                //props.put("key.deserializer", 
                //        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
                //     props.put("value.deserializer", 
                //        "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");

                return new ConsumerConfig(props);
            }

            public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
                String zooKeeper = args[0];
                String groupId = args[1];
                String topic = args[2];
                int threads = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);

                ConsumerGroupExample example = new ConsumerGroupExample(zooKeeper, groupId, topic);
                example.run(threads);

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

                }
                example.shutdown();
            }
        }






        import kafka.consumer.ConsumerIterator;
        import kafka.consumer.KafkaStream;

        public class ConsumerTest implements Runnable {
            private KafkaStream m_stream;
            private int m_threadNumber;
      private boolean  keepRunningThread

            public ConsumerTest(KafkaStream a_stream, int a_threadNumber,boolean  keepRunningThread) {
                m_threadNumber = a_threadNumber;
                m_stream = a_stream;
keepRunningThread = keepRunningThread;
            }

            public void run() {
                ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
              while(keepRunningThread) 
{
  try 
  {
    if(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(new String(it.next().message()));
    }
  } 
  catch(ConsumerTimeoutException ex) 
  {
    // Nothing serious timeout exception waiting for kafka message
  }
}‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍

               // System.out.println("Shutting down Thread: " + m_threadNumber);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to keep reading and handle timeout if no message. Code below will keep reading message without blocking your consumer. Your current code will also keep reading because of **while (it.hasNext())** however it will block consumer.

Remove following lines from main() because it will shutdown your consumer after 10 seconds

```
           // try 
           // {
           //     Thread.sleep(10000);
           // } catch (InterruptedException ie) {

           // }
           // example.shutdown();
```

Also add consumer.timeout.ms in your consumer configuration, else code will be blocking. Use keepRunningThread flag to control when you want to exit consumer loop

```
while(keepRunningThread) 
{
  try 
  {
    if(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(new String(it.next().message()));
    }
  } 
  catch(ConsumerTimeoutException ex) 
  {
    // Nothing serious timeout exception waiting for kafka message
    // Wait for 5 seconds
     Thread.sleep(5000);
  }
}‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍
```

For more detail please refer https://kafka.apache.org/07/documentation.html

(Copy paste from kafka doc)
consumer.timeout.ms : By default, this value is -1 and a consumer blocks indefinitely if no new message is available for consumption. By setting the value to a positive integer, a timeout exception is thrown to the consumer if no message is available for consumption after the specified timeout value.

Comment: if the value is set to -1 consumer will be blocked indefinitely . Does that means ,if producer send out a new message consumer wont be able to receive .

Comment: also i dint get the usage of keepRunningThread mentioned in code snnipet shared

Comment: consumer.timeout.ms will not stop consuming message, it will just specify how long to wait on it.hasNext() before throwing ConsumerTimeoutException. This will prevent kind of hanged consumer (if consumer is on main thread). In your case, it is not mandatory however is good to have.

keepRunningThread is flag to control when to exit consumer loop. You can use this to control when to stop consuming (instead of doing consumer shutdown after10 seconds, which you doing right now).

These are improvements, not main problem. Main problem is you called shutdown after 10 seconds